# C strcpy function and char*

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have a question regarding sending a pointer from `function1`to `function2` whereas `function2` changes that pointer.
lets take a look at a 'homemade' `strcpy`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void strcopy(char* targ, char* src) {
    while(*src) {
        *targ = *src;
        targ++;
        src++;
    }
    *targ = 0;
}
int main() {
    char* src = "this is aa string";
    char* targ = malloc(strlen(src)*sizeof(*targ)+1);
    strcopy(targ, src);
    printf("'%s'\n", targ);
    return 0;
}
```

the output is `'this is aa string'`

**the Question:**
how comes `targ` is pointing at the beginning of the string although we did `targ++` in the function?
it seems like we're sending the pointer by value!!
could anyone give a interpretation for that? Thanks.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html

Comment: C is "*Pass By Value*", always.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a pointer into a function, you're indeed passing the value of the pointer, your "targ" variable is a copy of the targ pointer in your main() function. Incrementing it inside strcopy() has no effect on your original pointer.
When you pass a variable by value, you're indeed passing an hidden pointer to the original variable, but in this case, you're storing the memory address into a new variable on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
void strcopy(char* targ, char* src)
```

When you call this API `targ` will get value of the pointer `targ` in `main()` so `targ` in main is never moved just the API is filling the values to the location rename the argument to something else for clarity.

```
void strcopy(char* dest, char* src)
```

So now you can read it as the pointer dest is moved to copy the values and `targ` in `main()` remains intact

Answer (score 0):

> it seems like we're sending the pointer by value

Indeed you are!

In C, everything is passed by value. Not until C++ did we have the notion of passing something by reference. In this case, you're passing a copy of the value of the pointer (i.e. the memory address that it is pointing to).

If you wanted to change what `targ` was pointing to, you could write this:

```
void strcopy(char** targ, char* src) { /* ... */ }

strcopy( &targ, src );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `targ` in your function and the `targ` in `main` are very different from each other. In fact, it might help your understanding if we changed the name of the parameter inside `strcopy`:

```
void strcopy(char* first_pointer, char* second_pointer) {
    while(*second_pointer) {
        *first_pointer = *second_pointer;
        first_pointer++;
        second_pointer++;
    }
    *first_pointer = 0;
}
```

I admit that is less readable, but it is actually identical to your version. Inside a function, the names of the parameters are really just 'nicknames' for 'first argument', 'second argument', and so on.

When you pass a value into a function, the 'name' of that value is meaningless until the function returns.

In C, everything is passed by value, by default. If you call `foo(x,y)`, then `x` and `y` will not change. If you put `&` in front, then it is possible to pass `x` 'by reference', allowing `foo` to modify `x` in the caller, but that is written `foo(&x,&y)`. If you don't see `&` in front of the value, then it is by value.

And passing a pointer by value means that the original pointer will continue to point to the same location. Of course, the data *pointed to* by the pointer might change sometime, but the pointer itself will point to the same location.

Comment: Although you probably meant to express the correct thing, this "*possible to pass the pointer 'by reference'*" is not correct, as pointers make no difference, they are passed by value, as any other varibale.

Comment: @alk. If `x` is a pointer, then `&x` is a pointer to a pointer, and that can be used to modify the 'original'  `&x`. I would argue that this is effectively 'by reference' - if we can change the value in the caller, then we've done something interesting. Although I guess that the callee then needs to do something special, i.e. `*first_arg = ...` instead of `first_arg = ...`, in order to make this change.  So what does 'by reference' mean in any language? The general ability to make changes in the stack of the caller? Or more specifically, the ability to do so *without* (explicit) dereferencing?

Comment: I agree. However this assumption  "*If `x` is a pointer...*" is missing in your answer.

Comment: I've made a small change to that sentence. Thanks for the feedback!